# Extra File lines being overwritten when output is put into specificied file lines

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, output, fstream, overwrite

Hey I have a bit of a silly question but I am having a bit of an issue with my code. I am trying to overwrite a line of a file, which is what it does, but the problem is that it overwrites other file lines as well. I am using C++ visual studios 2010. My code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const string FILENAME = "DatabaseTest.txt";

fstream& GoToLineI(fstream& file, int num)
{
file.seekg(ios::beg);
for(int i = 0; i < num+1; i++)
    file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
return file;
}

fstream& GoToLineO(fstream& file, int num)
{
file.seekp(ios::beg);
for( int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    //gets the length of the line.
    GoToLineI(file, i);
    string s;
    file >> s;
    long pos = file.tellp();
    file.seekp( pos + s.length() );
}
return file;
 }

int main()
{
fstream myfile(FILENAME.c_str(), ios::out);
myfile.close();
myfile.open(FILENAME.c_str(), ios::in | ios::out);

myfile << "Usernames:" << endl;

for( int j = 0; j < 101; j++)
    myfile << j << endl;

cout << "Where do you want to grab the data from?";
int i = 0;
cin >> i;

GoToLineI(myfile, i);

string line;
myfile >> line;

cout << line << endl;

GoToLineO(myfile, i);

if( myfile.is_open() )
{
    cout << "File should be writeable" << endl;
    myfile << "This should be at line 75" << endl;
}

myfile.seekp(ios::end);

system("PAUSE");

myfile.close();

return 0;
}
```

The issue may be in how I have my GoToLineO, which is how I find where to get to the output line, and It calls the GoToLineI in order to get the length of the lines until it reaches the right line to start displaying out put on. The output that this code generates is as such.

```
72
73
74
This should be at line 75
82
83
84
```

And it should look like this:

```
73
74
This should be at line 75
76
77
78
79
80
81
```

Any sort of insights or advice would be greatly appreciated.

edit: changed to only the important part of the outputs that should be shown.

Comment: What is difference between those two outputs? Could you please edit and post important lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you seek to a spot in a file, and then start writing there, what you write is going to overwrite the exact same number of bytes as what you write -- a little like an editor that's always in overwrite mode instead of insert mode.

If you want your result to remain a simple text file, about all you can do is copy the data to a new file, inserting your new data in the right place, then copying the remaining data from the original file into the new file after the new data you inserted.

If you want that result to have the same name as the original, you have a few choices -- you can copy the entire result back to your existing file, or (if you aren't worried about the possibility of multiple hard links to the original file) you can delete the original file, and rename the new one to the old name.

Comment: I see, so I'll have to basically save all the lines after where I plan to insert then reinsert those lines one at a time?

Comment: @KyleA.Groom: Not necessarily one at a time, but yes, you'll need to save that data and add it back in after the new data you write.